# Bootstrap row horizontal with a degree

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a little website here that has the rows going with a degree (see the image)

Each row has a different background colour etc. but they don't go totally horizontally. Each row (or its border rather) is slightly curved.

Any idea how to achieve such an effect?

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: This is a CSS issue, not specific to Bootstrap. Look a CSS "skew" eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979252/how-to-slant-skew-only-the-bottom-of-the-div

Comment: https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms

Comment: I am actually at the point of trying to "phrase it" and look for a solution online. I had a play with border-radius but does not seem like what I need.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe Thanks exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hi @Paul Mieczkowski, did my answer help you ? If so, can you please mark it as accepted ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the `transform:rotate` CSS property. See example below :

```css
.text-content {
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  padding: 50px;
}

.rotated-row {
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}

.orange-row {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #E5552A;
}
.blue-row {
  background: #1A99D5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row rotated-row orange-row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="text-content">
      <h1>ABOUT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row rotated-row blue-row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="text-content">
      <h1>SERVER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```